# Why doesn't spell damage affect all cards?

Tags: hearthstone

Why is the card *Arcane Intellect* not affected by an increase of the spell damage? With *Spell Damage* +2 and *Arcane Intelligence* I thought I could draw 4 cards.

[image: Arcane Intellect: Draw 2 Cards]

Are there more spell cards not affected by an increase of *Spell Damage*?

Comment: In short: spell damage increase doesn't now affect cards, if they 1. are not spell or 2. do not deal damage. Which is quite logical.:)

Comment: Drawing a card is not dealing damage, not sure why you think +damage is the same as +card draw

Comment: It used to be called Spell Power, but they changed it for this exact reason.

Comment: I am sorry for asking this question, but not in every language it is that clear like in English. I admit that it is MUCH more clear with English playing cards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Spell damage](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Spell_Damage) increases the damage done by a spell by a number of rules (see below). Drawing cards is not damage and as such isn't increased, healing is also not damage and is not increased.

Here is what *is* increased:

- Single target spells (say, Fireball) increase the damage by the listed amount.
- Spells that deal a fixed number of damage via several one damage hits (Arcane Missiles) will get extra shots per the amount of spell damage.
- Spells that do a base damage a variable number of times (just Bouncing Blade currently) will increase the base damage (so, +1 spell damage does 2 damage per hit for Bouncing Blade)
- Area of Effect spells will deal increased damage for every target they hit.

Spells with variable amount of damage (say Holy Wrath) will also be increased.
Damage from secrets is also increased.

Answer (score 5):

Drawing cards isn't dealing damage. I'm not sure why you'd think it is.

Spell damage +1 means that when a spell you control deals damage, it deals 1 more damage. It doesn't affect healing (which isn't damaged); it doesn't somehow cause animal companion to summon two minions (which isn't damage); it doesn't make buff spells buff more (still not damage); and it doesn't make Arcane Intellect draw more cards because, as I said, it's not damage.

**The only spells affected by +spell damage are spells that deal damage.** These spells will be highlighted if they would be buffed by a + spell damage effect while they are in your hand.